# Vb.NET instruction execution not triggered by event

Tags: arrays, vb.net, initializing

I have a very basic question on vb.NET, so basic that I didn't find any answer elsewhere.
I've written with VB express a code that is a simple form proposing various choices through checkboxes.
These choices have to be registered in an array, which I convert later into a textfile to be Perl-processed.
I'm searching a way to zeroise this big array with loops before use, but in fact I don't know how to execute instructions which wouldn't be triggered by events in my main form.
The frame looks like that :

```
Public Class Form1
'Variables declaration...

'Several boxes like that :
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
'Instructions...
End Sub

End Class
```

To launch this application, I simply click on the associated .exe file.
Basically, my question is : 
is there a way to execute instructions that wouldn't be launched by an user event, but immediatly launched when the main Form1 is shown ?
Sorry for being retarded, and thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: what does "zeroise" mean?  Does the the array contain the checkboxes or the checkstate?

Comment: By "zeroise", I mean that i fill the array with zeros. This array contains only "1" if the boxes are checked, "0" if not.

Comment: when you create the array it is already "zeroised". are you looking for a way to re-zeroise it? the nature of the title sounds like you dont know how to create a procedure

Comment: I didn't know that my array was filled with zero since it was created, sorry. I'm a great beginner at vb.net. I know how to create a procedure, but didn't know how to launch it immediatly with the first form, without being user-triggered. I'm grateful for your help, and sorry again for my low level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Form` will raise a `Shown` event when it is shown simply handle that:

```
Private Sub Form_Shown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    'Instructions...
End Sub
```

It can be better to do initialisation in the constructor right after the Winforms designer adds the comment: `'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call`

Comment: It works well. THANK YOU very much for this answer, and thanks again for having taken a piece of your time to help me. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

The `Form.Load` event for instance gets launched as soon as the form is about to be shown :)

Comment: It also works. Thank you. It's not so obvious when you try to learn by yourself...